# Getting Undefined Property Notice Even Though Its Defined

Tags: php, yii

I just started on YII today and have an existing project to work on. When I am trying to run the project, I am getting a following Notice -

> Notice: Undefined property: CWebApplication::$v_glob in ..\controllers\SiteController.php on line 10

When I check `SiteController` class I do see that `v_glob` is indeed defined. This is how the class looks -

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{ 
    public function init()
    {
          Yii::app()->v_glob;
          parent::init();
    } 

   /* other functions */
}
```

Due to this notice I am getting fatal errors wherever I am trying to call its member functions. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, take a look carefully at the notice :

> Undefined property: **CWebApplication**::$v_glob

The attribute `v_glob` has to be defined in `CWebApplication`, not in your `SiteController`...

PS : And the following line is not really useful:

```
Yii::app()->v_glob;
```

Comment: I do see a framework file CWebApplication.php. Do I need to define `v_glob ` in this file ?

Comment: No, don't modify Yii core class, you should extend it. But before you should try to remove `Yii::app()->v_glob;` since I don't see the point...

Comment: thanks.. and sorry i am asking too many questions.. but could you please also explain to me how to extend that class ?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/126/setting-and-getting-systemwide-static-parameters/ might help.